# how to copy down excel formulas on new tab in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 2 tabs. The "AccountDetail" tab contains multiple variable rows of data (including one header row). The "MasterDetail" tab has 2 rows of data (row 1 is a header row, row 2 is a row of formulas).

I want to count the number of data rows on the AccountDetail tab and copy down the formulas on the MasterDetail tab for the equivalent number of rows with data from the AccountDetail tab. This is what I have so far. I could use some suggestions.

```
Sub CopyFormulas_Down()
Dim LastRow As Long

EndRow = AccountDetail.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MasterDetail.Range("A2:AZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:AZ" &   LastRow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems you have a simple typo error in your code. You are declaring `LastRow` which you are also passing to the `AutoFill()` function, but you are using `EndRow` to store what you got from your count, so that for one is a reason you are not getting the expected value.

Also i for myself noticed a sometimes unpredictable behavior depending on Excel version used. There are different methods to count the rows in a Sheet, but from what i have experienced with different versions, this is what i use to get the last row:

```
' get last row of worksheet
Public Function GetWSLastRow(ByRef wsSheet As Worksheet) As Double

    ' simply return 0 if no Worksheet was passed
    If IsNothing(wsSheet) Then
        GetWSLastRow = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' first we try using Find(any) to get last row
    On Error GoTo errLRFindError
    GetWSLastRow = wsSheet.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ' if there was no error we will just exit function
    ' otherwise we jump to next method of determining last row

endGetLastRow:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

errLRFindError:
    ' try getting last row by querying for UsedRange's row count
    On Error GoTo errLRUsedRangeError
    GetWSLastRow = wsSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Resume endGetLastRow

errLRUsedRangeError:
    ' last chance rows count, but you should not end up here anyhow
    GetWSLastRow = wsSheet.Rows.Count
    Resume endGetLastRow

End Function
```

So then using this function your code would look like this:

```
Sub CopyFormulas_Down()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = GetWSLastRow(AccountDetail)
    MasterDetail.Range("A2:AZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:AZ" &   LastRow)
End Sub
```

Or even shorter:

```
Sub CopyFormulas_Down()
    MasterDetail.Range("A2:AZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:AZ" &   GetWSLastRow(AccountDetail))
End Sub
```

Hope that was it.